# Why am I getting null values on the server side after sending a post request by Postman

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have created a RESTful webservice using Spring boot to add a record to `H2` database but when I send data from postman to my handler method I get null values on the server side and on the response sent to the client side as well, could anybody help me?

Eclipse Snapshot [image: Eclipse snapshot]
Postman Snapshot [image: Postman Snapshot]

My Controller Code:

```
@RestController
public class AlienController {

    @Autowired
    AlienRepo repo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return"home.jsp";
    }
    
    @PostMapping(path="/alien")
    public Alien addAlien(Alien alien) {
        System.out.println(alien);
        repo.save(alien);
        return alien;
    }
```

My DAO Class:

```
    @Entity
    public class Alien {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int aid;
        private String aname;
        private String lang;
        
        public int getAid() {
            return aid;
        }
        public void setAid(int aid) {
            this.aid=aid;       
        }
        
        public String getAname() {
            return aname;
        }
        public void setAname(String aname) {
            this.aname=aname;       
        }
        
        public String getLang() {
            return lang;
        }
        public void setLang(String lang) {
            this.lang=lang;         
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Alien Info: Aid=" + aid + ", Aname=" + aname + ", Lang=" +lang;
        }       
    }
```

My AlienRepository code:

```
    public interface AlienRepo extends JpaRepository<Alien, Integer>{   
    }
```

Comment: If you try to send a json object as a body of the request you need to specify that by adding the @RequestBody annotation :  public Alien addAlien(@RequestBody Alien alien)

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks @OussamaZAGHDOUD .

Comment: @OussamaZAGHDOUD you should probably post that as an answer

Comment: For the future: please learn how to use the markdown language properly to format/indent your code input. Dont just **assume** you know how it works, and put down something, to then ignore that it really doesn't look like it should. You see, that link "help" there, and "preview", they exist for a reason. To help you coming up with quality content.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the annotation `@RequestBody`

```
   public Alien addAlien(@RequestBody Alien alien)
```

You should inform Spring that you are waiting for a `HttpRequest`  that contains a `Body` , Spring will automatically deserialize the inbound `HttpRequest` body onto Java object